# How to get vertical line and horizontal Bar chart in same without gap?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I am trying to get bar chart as horizontal with vertical line. If there is `boundaryGap: false` for `yAxis` then bar chart goes below `xAxis`.

[image]

If I do not remove `boundaryGap`, then `yAxis` starts in middle of values. The vertical line starts in half of value.

[image]

Is it possible for vertical line to appear touching xAxis while barChart can be with boundary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later realized that it can be achieved using  field `markLine`. The [API](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markLine) has all details and can be simply used as:

`markLine:{ data:[1,2,3] }`